# upload custom logs in s3 to cloudwatch for metrics monitoring

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudwatch

I created a custom app that automatically uploads logs to s3.
Is there a way to push those logs to cloudwatch from s3 for analysis and alerting?
I'm aware that I can use a cloudwatch agent to push directly to cloudwatch from the app but there are complications involved in that option.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use Cloudwatch Events to listen to S3 changes. Not sure about if you can get the data from the S3 file, or just a trigger saying that a new log has been added.

You could also use S3 event notifications (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html) connected either to a lambda or SQS, and from there create the logs to Cloudwatch. (similar to what was suggested by @marcin)

A better solution, but one that is a bit beyond the scope of the question, would be to send your logs through Kinesis Firehose and from there add the Cloudwatch and S3 logs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any out-of-the-box mechanism for that provided by AWS. But I think it could be relatively easy to **develop**.

Namely, you can create [S3 notification](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html) for a PUT of a new log file from your app to S3. The event would trigger a **lambda function**. The function would get the file and using **AWS SDK**, e.g. boto3's [put_log_events](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/logs.html#CloudWatchLogs.Client.put_log_events), it would send the log events to CloudWatch logs.